# How to arrange an array in a way better than this in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to arrange an array in a way better than this in Swift?
I'm sure there is an easier and shorter way to do it?!
I've used for loop and if conditions, then I've assigned the smallest ones in separate array.
I think this can be done with one single array feature..

How to sort an array of numbers in order?

```
var sortarray = [0, 0, 0, 0]
var arrio = [56, 78, 54, 91]
var smallestNumber = 0
var indexNumber = 0
print("unorder array was: \(arrio)")
for i in 0...3 { 
    if arrio[0] < arrio[1] {
        smallestNumber = arrio[0]
        indexNumber = 0
    } else {
        smallestNumber = arrio[1]
        indexNumber = 1
    }
    if smallestNumber >= arrio[2] {
        smallestNumber = arrio[2]
        indexNumber = 2
    }
    if smallestNumber >= arrio[3] {
        smallestNumber = arrio[3]
        indexNumber = 3
    }
    sortarray[i] = smallestNumber
    arrio[indexNumber] = 1000000 
}
print("array after sorting from smaller to bigger has become: \(sortarray)")
```

Comment: _" I think this can be done with one single array feature"_, did you check the documentation?

Comment: It would be highly appreciated if you could share the related documentation..

Comment: Start [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation)

Comment: Many thanks Joakim Danielson

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mean you need to sort the array in ascending order thats all

```
        var arrio = [56, 78, 54, 91]
        arrio = arrio.sorted(by: < )
        debugPrint(arrio)
```

**O/P:**

> [54, 56, 78, 91]

**EDIT 1:**

As Leo pointed out in comments below, it makes absolute sense to use mutating function `sort` on this array to sort it in place instead of using `sorted(by:` which will create a new sorted array. Array is declared as `var` ( You cant use mutating function like `sort` on a `let`). Hence updating the answer to reflect the same

```
        var arrio = [56, 78, 54, 91]
        arrio.sort()
        debugPrint(arrio)
```

Is this what you want

Comment: Why not simply `arrio.sort()`? You should use the mutating method.

Comment: @leo-dabus : Agreed, wasnt thinking of it. Should have realized array is declared as `var` I could mutate it instead of creating a new array

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `sorted(by:)` to create a sorted version of an array, or `sort(by:)` to sort the array in place. (Both actually operate on objects that conform to the `Sequence` protocol. An array is conforms to `Sequence`.) Which version you use depends on your use-case.